# Way of mocking a REST service in Grails

Tags: rest, grails, mocking

In my grails 2.5.4 application, I want to call a rest service which is not available at the moment. I know the request and the reply of my request. Can you suggest me a way of mocking the service?

Answer (score 1):

How about creating a stub webservice with hardcoded responses?

This shows u a quick and dirty way to make a simple webservice: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19226-01/820-7627/giqaa/

I figure you can use that and modify the code netbeans generates like this:

```
 @GET
    @Produces("text/html")
    public String getHtml() {
        return "Your Hardcoded response";
    }
```

Comment: I would like a "clean" and nice solution since I will have to apply it to many web services and I will be using it for some time. Your solution using stubs sounds interesting. Could you please provide me with a good example or/and grails/groovy APIs used?

Comment: Hmm well i dont have experience using groovy or grails, but i know u can easily create a webservices using netbeans (java ee version) all libraries for making the webservice are already included in the IDE. Ill udpate my answer with an example.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible for you to use external mocking software? 
There are for example Soap UI, mockloki, or other similar software. Soap UI will install software on your machine, while mockloki is accessible through web application.

[www.souapui.org](http://www.soaupui.org), 
[www.mockloki.com](http://www.mockloki.com)

Greets